# How to define the return type of a function according to the input parameters with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, function, conditional-types

I have a function with an object as argument:

```js
// Types
type Params = {
  first: string;
  second: number;
  third?: boolean;
};
type FunctionA = (params: Params) => { [key: string]: any } | void;

// Function
const functionA: FunctionA = params => {
  // ... do something
  if (params.third) {
    return {one: "object"}
  }
};
```

So basically, what I want to achieve is that if `third` has been submitted, I want that the function return type is `{[key: string]: any}`. If `third` **is not** submitted, I want it to be `never`.

I have found solutions where the **return type** of a function changes according to the argument which has been returned but nothing, if the object is an argument and with a return type which is different from the argument type.

Is this even possible?

Thanks! Any help appreciated!

Comment: Given your code, it seems like you want to return `void` instead of `never` when `third` is not submitted.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. Sorry, I have made a copy & paste mistake here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

LE: After reading the question better I think this is what you want:

```
type Params = {
  first: string;
  second: number;
  third?: boolean;
};

function A(params: Omit<Params, "third">): void
function A(params: Required<Params>): { [key: string]: any }
function A(params: Params): { [key: string]: any } | void {
  if (params.third === undefined) {
    return
  }

  return {...params}
}
```

Again, you are overloading the function, but this time you are declaring one without `third` in the params and another where all fields are required, including `third`.

You can see this in action in this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM5QLxQN4CgpQBmAlgqsAFxTkLEB2A5gNz7UQDGA9nQCZV0BXZACMICFgWAALUjwD8VYZ04AbCHDosAvi1yEBddsGLcoAQQAUYRClRUA8smLAAPPCRoANFABE02T4AfACUVABunMQ8egZGJnTmVjZoVABKEACOAqQQPG7JqCFU2FAA2gDWECBUNPQMALpUGiBQWjGGxqaW1h52sAWhOGWV1dTAtIyNUM2tUAA+UBFROKzEhFBJvQB0-gg8mBhYBjwQJHS5wSsEBAgQwAIIdKxtrLf3jzhbXz22bS9cdHI0wAjJhEtgSGRKL4AEw+byoDjcPhQAAsWmCuABQLgMLBlghpHIVB8cIRSN4VAArN5dijCHAVIiMbggA).

You can declare 2 functions with 2 and 3 params and then implement it. Something similar to this:

```
function A (first: string, second: string, third: boolean): {[key: string]: any}
function A (first: string, second: string): never
function A (first: string, second: string, third?: boolean) {
  if (third === undefined) {
    throw new Error("error message")
  }

  return {first, second, third}
}
```

Now your IDE or any code helper should know that if you pass 2 params you have a return type and if you pass 3 another.

Note: I don't see a valid reason for returning `never` when not passing the third argument. Is almost like you want to make the 3rd one mandatory and not optional.

Comment: Thank you for the very quick answer! Interesting solution but would this also work with an object a single argument? And yes, the return type is supposed to be `void` of course, sorry!

Comment: What do you mean about a single argument? You can have as many overloads as you want. Even the same number of arguments of different types. You do need to have a union in the implementation though. NVM, I understand what you want now.

Comment: It would be `functionA({first: string, second: number, third?: boolean})`, so there is **only one argument** - the object containing `first`, `second` and `third`.

Comment: Using a single argument cannot work. Typing is done at compile time, passing the arguments is done at runtime. They are distinct. When using multiple function declaration TS can figure out at the call site which of the function you want, otherwise it cannot.

Comment: Thanks for the updated solution! Guess it's almost what I need. Final question: how would functional overloads work if `functionA` is exported from a file? Can I just keep the overloads in the same file as the function is defined?

Comment: TS should be able to pick up the types when importing the function in another module.